# use fulltext formsof inflectional to generate terms

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

Is there a way to use the FullText query components to generate the list of words in the FullText dictionary that are the inflectional formsof a word?

This query would give me matches based on the query.

```
select *
from keywords
WHERE CONTAINS(keyword, 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, migrate)')
```

I am interested in words that it's using as matches.
I want a list of words like

```
migrate
migrates
migration
migrations
```

Essentially the word's inflectional / conjugated forms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the words that will be used in the match with the [sys.dm_fts_parser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280463.aspx) function in SQL Server.

The Syntax

```
sys.dm_fts_parser('query_string', lcid, stoplist_id, accent_sensitivity)
```

I won't go in details for the parameters values, but the "[lcid](http://www.pagedowntech.com/faq/faq.aspx?faqid=21)" is important.  In the example below I'm using 1033 which is for English - US.  I've tried with 1036, French - Standard, and for sure I didn't get any results beside the word itself, since the word doesn't exist in the French dictionary.

Example

```
SELECT display_term
FROM SYS.DM_FTS_PARSER('FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, welcome)', 1033, 0, 0)
```

Result

```
welcome's
welcomed
welcomes
welcomes'
welcoming
welcome
```